# Find in S3 Specific files from User write back to respected user folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

The question is using Lambda function is it possible to look through an S3 bucket with User folder's for a specific file name (Ex: Test1.txt and Text2.txt) Inside the file is just random number. Then basically write back a text file into the grabbed file respected folder basically saying "Test1.txt and Test2.txt has been touched.". If possible in python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Use [Amazon's AWS SDK](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Here's an [example for downloading a file from S3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html). The API for listing files and uploading files is pretty similar.